# Using PHP build tools via composer install leads to many dependencies

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, toolchain

I'm in the middle of setting up a new system for continuous integration and delivery.

As PEAR is about to EOL for most of the packages (like phpunit) i switched to composer, which seems a good idea, as i need it for the projects.

so to test my integration's server i started with a very simple composer.json:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*",
        "phpmd/phpmd" : "2.0.*",
        "pdepend/pdepend" : "2.0.0",
        "zerkalica/php-code-browser": "dev-master",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.*",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "*",
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

this leads to **230MB Vendor directory**.

for the full list of packages which are installed see:
https://gist.github.com/rufinus/14b271f61e143364452f

Is this an expected result?

Should i switch to the PHAR files and have them stored in a bin directory inside the project?

What is the best practice? (without pear)

Comment: Why would git complain about the amount you have pulled ? surely you are not commit your vendor folder ? you would put vendor/* inside your .gitignore and then you deploy your code to your server etc you would do a composer update

Comment: `Could not fetch https://api.github.com/[...], enter your GitHub credentials to go over the API rate limit` see https://circleci.com/docs/composer-api-rate-limit for details.

Comment: Are you using ssh keys ? are you putting in you github creds ?

Comment: the github rate limiting is not a problem, was just a funny sidenote.

Comment: So do you still have an issue ?

Comment: i find it hard to belive i have to use 230MB of vendor libs just to have a build toolchain with composer, when phar or pear packages use way less space.

Comment: edit for better understanding what i'm asking

Comment: it looks right, my vendor folder is "173M ./vendor"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure composer to download each package instead of cloning it. This should save you some space and time.

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*",
        "phpmd/phpmd" : "2.0.*",
        "pdepend/pdepend" : "2.0.0",
        "zerkalica/php-code-browser": "dev-master",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.*",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "*",
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

To test, remove `vendor`, `composer.lock` and run `composer install` again. Now it should download each package, instead of cloning it.

As a side note. Try to use a specific version instead of "*" or "dev-master". phpcpd for example I know for sure that is frequently tagged.